# Stored procedure cut value of ntext parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ntext

I have a strange issue: i created a simple stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
@id INT,
@ntextParameter NTEXT,
...
UPDATE xxx SET [Field] = @ntextParameter WHERE ID = @id
```

but when i execute it with a long text, it update the table and simply cut the text without any visible error

Comment: Consider not using the deprecated `NTEXT` type and switching to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, it's much easier to use in string operations.

Comment: [ntext, text and image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them.". That notice has existed for **over a decade**. It's beyond time to stop using them.

Comment: What size length `nvarchar` is `field`?

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought that the nvarchar was only 4000 character, but i checked and i find out that now nvarchar(max) is way longer in new version of sql server, so i will fix the database

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) and [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) in the comments the NTEXT type field is deprecated, I found out that NVARCHAR(MAX) is longer that 4000 character (maximum storage size is 2^30-1 characters (2 GB)) and that I need